# Install more memory to my PC

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade, dell-vostro

I have Dell Vostro 3750 laptop with 8 GB RAM (2x4GB). Does anyone know if it's possible to install more 8 GB (2x8GB) to have 16 GB on that laptop? Or where I can see whether it supports 16 GB RAM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dell hasn't tested RAM-units over 4GB per slot. But many people tell, that they are running 16GB of RAM without any problems. So officially, there is a limit of 8GB but inofficial you can use up to 16GB.

[Dell-Community-Thread for example](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19441081.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @chris but it all depends with the processor. If you are upgrading the memory to 16GB i think you are voiding the warranty and moreover it does not work always but give it a shot if you are interested.

In the hindsight, I don't think you will be needing 16GB memory as most of the software's run pretty good with 8GB except the memory intensives ones.